# Using Memcached and php session problem occurred

Tags: php, session, memcached

I'm trying to use memcache to handle session in PHP.

I still want to use

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name']="someone's name";
    session_destroy();
?>
```

style of starting, registering and destroying session.

This is what I have in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
extension = memcache.so
memcache.allow_failover = 1
memcache.redundancy = 1
memcache.session_redundancy = 2

session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = "tcp://NOT.LOCALHOST.SERVER.IP:11211"
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0 
session.cookie_path = /
```

and I'm getthing this error:

> Notice: session_start(): Server NOT.LOCALHOST.SERVER.IP (tcp 11211) failed with:
>   Connection refused (111) in somefile.php on some line.

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should verify if

- Your remote server's 11211 port is open
- If your local server is authorized to access that port

I can't comment yet, so I have to post this as an answer.

Comment: 11211 port are open and authorized to access that port

Comment: Is memcached enabled on the remote server ?

Comment: Yes it is enabled. I tried to start memcached again and it says that it is already running.

Comment: should I configure on memcached access IP list in some conf file?

Comment: Thank you the problem has solved. The memcached was not properly run.

Comment: How can I make this memcached start when the server starts like apache?